# How does Visual Studio 2022 interact with MSBuild and how to customize this process ? How to manage persistant data (ex: version)?

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2022

I'm trying to figure out how to better manage the build of my .Net projects in visual studio. but I have some hard time putting all the parts together...

The only entry point I found are the beforeBuild/afterBuild events I can access from the project properties.
However, It seems I can only put batch code in there so as a first step I can do
call $(ProjectDir)\MSBuild\prebuild.bat which allows me to be already a bit more flexible.

Now lets say I want to fiddle with MSBuild properties (or visual studio properties... it is not completly clear at this point, as it seems to be real mess, changing a lot with visual studio versions).
For exemple if I want to set $(VersionPrefix) (for a more concrete exemple,what i'm trying to dofirst is having the versionPrefix autoUpdated with a build number and later with git ... but going step by step), it seems I could do it like this in an msbuild target

```
<PropertyGroup>
<VersionPrefix>1.2.3.4</VersionPrefix>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Should I edit directly the project file and include this in the PreBuild Target ? It seems to be a bit heavy and manual so I'm afraid I'm heading in the wrong direction.
But anyway found out this property is reset anytime I rebuild the project... so I guestt versionPrefix isn't the place where I would like to store any permanent version id... What i don't understand is that according to my research there used to be a file where this would be written in older version of visual studio (Assembly info), but it seems it is not the case anymore...

Do you have any pointers about how I should do this kind of jobs and If I'm trying to do it in a proper way ? I find it strangly hard to figure it out with .Net projects in visual studio. Available documentation seems to be either lacking or outdated...

as the concrete exemple, I tried to write this :

```
<Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
<Exec Command="echo $(VersionPrefix)" />
<PropertyGroup>
<VersionPrefix>1.2.3.4</VersionPrefix>
</PropertyGroup>
</Target>
<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
<Exec Command="echo $(VersionPrefix) />
</Target>
```

I would expect $(VersionPrefix) to stay at 1.2.3.4 for the project after the first build but it comes back to the default value at each build.

Comment: I also tried something like <Target Name="VersionManager" BeforeTargets="PostBuild">...</Target> which works but I feel that putting something like this directly in the project file might be dangerous as the way to edit directly the poject file in visual studio (unloading, edititng) let me know that it is not desirable.

Comment: When extending msbuild directly, you would have to hand edit the project and/or targets files. Instead of putting them in the project file directly, you can also put it in your code in a targets file and only update the project file to include the targets file.

Comment: I found that I could generate a Resources.resx. Seems like a good place to define variable. that persist between build. but cannot figure out how to edit them during build. (if it is a good option)

Comment: When extending msbuild you should NOT update the project file from inside MSBUILD. You can pass in a value from the commandline by passing in `/p:VersionPrefix=1.2.3.4`. That would keep your project files stable.

Comment: There are all kinds of built-in caching mechanisms built into Visual Studio and MsBuild and it's really hard to correctly extend the build process to auto-reload the changes while the build process has already kicked off. Incorrectly adding targets, will also cause msbuild to do full rebuilds all the time instead of it being able to cache intermediate results.

Comment: In most cases there will be a build-server (aka. CI server) involved to handle things like build counters. The patterns for versions I have used are: 1) Set major.minor.patch in the assemblyInfo-file by hand. 2) Set the major.minor.patch in a git tag, and let the CI set the version number. In either case the CI will set the build number.

Comment: Here is guidance on extending the build process. If you do decide to pull the version number from a file and conditionally update that file from the build process, just store it in a text file, plain, json or XML, it doesn't matter and load the value as part of the build. Make sure you  specify the `outputs` and create an itemgroup that references the file that stores the version number, that way MsBuild can track what other targets to rebuild. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/incremental-builds?view=vs-2022#output-inference

Answer (score 1):

To sum up elements of answers given in comments.

A first mistake is to try to store persistant information during the build process into the project file. This should be done externally.

Some solutions:

- Use external file (json, xml, ...)
- Use git tag
- Use a build-server, that might store some infos

Taking this into account I'll try to use both a file and git tags for my next tests.
My main issue for now would be to find a proper way to access data stored in a file at build, it seems it needs to be done through a batch file called before build.

which has led to this msbuild target :

```
<Target Name="VersionManager" BeforeTargets="PostBuild">

        <JsonPeek ContentPath="$(ProjectDir)\Build\BuildInfo.json" Query="$.Version">
            <Output TaskParameter="Result" ItemName="VersionJSON" />
        </JsonPeek>

        <Exec Command="git rev-parse --short HEAD" ConsoleToMSBuild="true">
            <Output TaskParameter="ConsoleOutput" PropertyName="GitId" />
        </Exec>

        <PropertyGroup>
            <BuildNumber>@(VersionJSON -> '%(build)')</BuildNumber>
            <VersionMajor>@(VersionJSON -> '%(major)')</VersionMajor>
            <VersionMinor>@(VersionJSON -> '%(minor)')</VersionMinor>
            <LastGitCommit>$(GitId)</LastGitCommit>
        </PropertyGroup>

        <Exec Command="echo fullVersion=$(VersionMajor).$(VersionMinor).$(LastGitCommit).$(BuildNumber)" />
    </Target>
```

I used JsonPeek to look at a json file in which i can store all persistant information I which about the project. my next step will be to use JsonPoke to increment the build number in the json file.